# Some programs in windows 10 suddenly have huge fonts

Tags: windows, windows-10

I don't know what changed , but suddenly some programs like Notepad++ , QGIS , Wireshark have huge fonts in GUI and I can't use them.

I've checked the font scaling and its on 100% and I don't see any indication that they are increased on any windows settings.

This happens in some apps and not all over windows.

Attached example , any idea how to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description and my previous experience with the smaller font, make the following suggestions:

1. **Make sure the application is running**
2. **Right-click on the icon on the desktop > properties**

[image]

3. **Go to the compatibility tab > Disable display scaling on high DPI settings**

[image]

Note:

In Windows 10 Version 1703 and later version of Windows, the text of the **Disable display scaling on high DPI settings** option is changed to **Override high DPI scaling behavior**, scaling performed by: **Application**.

4. **Restart the application**

Please let me know if it works. I hope this answer will be helpful to you!

Answer (score -1):

In Windows: Select the Start  menu, then type change display settings in the search box on the taskbar. From the list of results, choose Change display settings and then choose the size under Scale and layout.

Comment: This is not related to scale , everything is 100%